# Set custom interval for AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

How can I set alarm between two custom days. For example from 19/12/2017 - 20/12/2018.   How can I do it ?. Please help me

Comment: Please post your code, what have you tried?

Comment: you want repeating alarms after some specific time, isn't it?

Comment: @Jorgesys alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKE_UP,  AlarmManager.Interval_Day, alarmIntent)   I want to set custom interval instead of AlarmManager.Interval_Day

Comment: @MovsesMartirosyan please accept an answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` is only a long representation of the number of milliseconds in a day.

You can pass any custom long value you want.

For example, 2 days and 3 hours would be

```
`AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` * 2 + `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR` * 3
```

Or you can just calculate like that

1 second = 1000

1 minute = 60 * second ...etc.

If you want to fire alarm on a specific date in the future, you can use `AlarmManager.set()` or `AlarmManager.setExact()`..etc and you pass the milliseconds from a date/calendar object that corresponds to your date.

`new Date(2017, 5, 12).getTime()` or `Calendar.getTime().getTime()`

Comment: But for example I want to add schedule from 20/12/2017 - 4/01/2018 there are 17 days between it. How can schedule for 17 days.  How can I get that 17 days. How to calculate ?

Comment: I also want to know how to start alarm on a specific date. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `setExact` and then inside each `PendingIntent`, first check to see if the time is before your threshold and then if it is, `setExact` again.

```
public void scheduleAlarm() {
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent("myIntent");
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    alarmMgr.setExact(TYPE, ALARM_INTERVAL, alarmIntent);
}

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("myIntent")) {
            //do something
            if (timeHasNotPassedYet(Calendar.getInstance())) {
                scheduleAlarm();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The alarm will be scheduled until `timeHasNotPassedYet` returns false. At that time the new alarm will not be rescheduled.